# Confirm para eliminar artículo

Tags: php, javascript, poo, netbeans, xampp

Tengo este método creado para eliminar mi artículo. Está creado con POO y Programación por capas. (Capa Datos, Negocio, Presentacion), este método está en la de Datos.

```
public function eliminarArticulo(){
    /** Comprueba si existe conexión con la base de datos. */
    if ($this->getPdocon()) {
        /** Prepara la sentencia SQL. */
        $resultado = $this->getPdocon()->prepare(
            "DELETE FROM Articulos
                WHERE idArticulo='$idArticulo'");
        /** Ejecuta la sentencia preparada y comprueba un posible error. */
        if ($resultado->execute()) {
            /** Devuelve true si se ha conseguido. */
            return true;
        }
    }
    /** Devuelve false si se ha producido un error. */
    return false;

}
```

Luego tengo otro método que conecta con el de la capa de Datos, y está en la de Negocio.

```
public function eliminarArticulo(){
    /** Instancia un objeto de la clase. */
    $bdarticulo = new BDArticulos();
    /** Se comprueba si existe la conexión con el servidor de BD. */
    if ($bdarticulo->getPdocon()) {
        /** Elimina un articulo y comprueba un posible error. */
        if ($bdarticulo->eliminarArticulo()) {
            return true;
        }
                    return false;
        }
    }
```

Y en la capa de presentación, tengo una tabla en la cual en las columnas tengo un icono y he hecho un JS con un confirm. ¿Como hago para que el JS me borre mediante el ID el artículo de la base de datos? Tengo que llamar al método de la capa de datos, pero no sé como.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           function preguntar() {
              var respuesta = confirm("¿Estás seguro que deseas eliminar el artículo?"); 
              if(respuesta == true)
              {
                  return true;
              }
              else{
                  return false;
              }
}

</script>
```

Aquí tengo como hago para que al hacer clic en el icono, me salga el confirm.

```
<tbody>
                      <?php
                      $articulosObjeto = new BDArticulos();
                      if($articulosObjeto->mostrarArticulo()){
                          foreach($articulosObjeto->mostrarArticulo() as $fila){?>
                      <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $fila['idArticulo'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila['descripcion'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila['anoalta'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila['anobaja'] ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center" "><a href="#" onclick="return preguntar()"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a> </td>
                      </tr>     
                         <?php }
                      }?>
                      </tr
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cambia el `href` para que apunte a la ruta del controlador, incluyendo ID del artículo y la acción para borrar.

Comment: Me perdido..puedes ponerlo en codigo?

Comment: ¿Cómo armas las rutas en tu proyecto? ¿Cómo debería ser la URL para eliminar un artículo? Por cierto, el error de la imagen es porque falta `$` en el nombre de la variable.

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que cuando hagas la carga de los datos de la tabla definas dentro de la función preguntar un parámetro en este caso sería idArticulo

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $fila['idArticulo'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila['descripcion'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila['anoalta'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fila['anobaja'] ?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center" ">
      <a href="#" onclick="return preguntar(<?php echo $fila['idArticulo'] ?>)">
         <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
      </a> 
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Luego tendríamos la función con dicho Id por parámetro

```
 function preguntar(idArticulo) {
          var respuesta = confirm("¿Estás seguro que deseas eliminar el artículo?"); 
          if(respuesta == true)
          {
              eliminarArticulo(idArticulo);
              return true;
          }
          else{
              return false;
          }
  }
```

Y por último tendríamos la ejecución de la función eliminarArticulo(idArticulo)

```
public function eliminarArticulo(idArticulo){
    /** Comprueba si existe conexión con la base de datos. */
    if ($this->getPdocon()) {
        /** Prepara la sentencia SQL. */
        $resultado = $this->getPdocon()->prepare(
            "DELETE FROM Articulos
                WHERE idArticulo='$idArticulo'");
        /** Ejecuta la sentencia preparada y comprueba un posible error. */
        if ($resultado->execute()) {
            /** Devuelve true si se ha conseguido. */
            return true;
        }
    }
    /** Devuelve false si se ha producido un error. */
    return false;

}
```

Comment: No me funciona, cuando pongo:  eliminarArticulo(idArticulo) me sale error...no me hace nada..

Comment: Me falto agregar el id del articulo en la creación de la tabla cada en el método preguntar, revisa si ahora te funciona

Comment: No entendí esto ultimo... Perdona me ignorancia, es que soy nueva en esto...

Comment: Primer caja de código, revisa en los <tr></tr> en el evento del onclick de la etiqueta <a>

Comment: Eso esta bien, el problema es que en la funcion donde tengo el delete.. el (idArticulo) al ponerlo, me sale error..no me deja

Comment: Has definido el parámetro en la función delete ? public function eliminarArticulo(idArticulo){

Comment: claro, lo he puesto tal cual lo has pasado pero no me deja me pone error de syntaxis pero tengo todo bien

Comment: Y en la otra función de eliminar articulo también lo pasas por parámetros ?

Comment: no, ninguna de las funciones.

Comment: por eso no te está funcionando, debes pasar el parámetro por todas las funciones

Comment: Si lo hago, pero me sale error de sintaxys.. Bueno da igual..dejalo, ya le buscaré otra solución. Gracias.

Comment: El error de sintaxis pasa por qué hay algo mal escrito, si puedas adjuntar una screenshot estaría genial

Comment: No sé si la verás, la acabo de poner en el código de arriba.

Comment: Revisa has insertado mal la imagen

Comment: Da igual, no me deja añadir la foto tampoco.

Comment: https://codepen.io/harryheman/embed/gOMWdad?default-tab=&theme-id= mira ese repo capaz te sirve